# Saving a value from textbox in char with specified array location in C++/CLI Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I have this code from a MFC project

```
char holder[4];
int tempVal;
char tempstr[262];

tBlkNo.GetWindowText( holder, 3 );
sscanf( holder, "%d", &tempVal );
```

Now I plan to follow this code and implement it in a Windows Form Application. Now the problem is I cannot use GetWindowText in the Windows Form application since it is not a member of the textbox. How do I save a value from the textbox of Windows Form to an specified array location just like the sample code above but in C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
int tempval;
bool ok = int::TryParse(myTextBox.Text, tempval); //Parameter is taken by reference
```